# how to set SQL Server login wizard to show AD groups as checked by default

Tags: sql-server

When adding an AD login to an instance of SQL Server, the groups checkbox is unchecked by default. Because we abstract security into groups, it would be easier for the DBA if that were checked by default.

Is there a setting or flag that will make the groups checkbox show checked by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking the wrong question here. The real issue is not how to check a box, it's how to automate the login creation process so that you don't have to do it manually. If you find yourself clicking through the same dialog boxes repeatedly, the best solution is always to script or otherwise automate the process.

In this case, you can script your permissions setup: a plain .sql script that you run with sqlcmd.exe, a PowerShell script using Smo, or whatever other language you prefer. Then you have something you can run against any server, automate, schedule, document, put under source control etc.

If you want to use plain TSQL, see `CREATE LOGIN` in Books Online. For PowerShell using Smo, check the Smo documentation for the `Login` object.